# Micronaut Error invoking scheduled task Failed to inject value for parameter [repository]

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

i have something very simple

```
@Singleton
open class ServerProcessor(private val repository: ServerRepository) {

 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = "2s", initialDelay = "10s")
 open fun runPollJobs() {
     some other stuff happens here
 }
}
```

When i run that, i get

> 16:59:03.686 [scheduled-executor-thread-1] ERROR
> i.m.s.DefaultTaskExceptionHandler - Error invoking scheduled task
> Failed to inject value for parameter [repository] of class:
> ...ServerProcessor

The strange thing is, that problem comes and goes. Sometimes its enough to rebuild the application. Sometimes it it stays if it happened once.

Very annoying cause i have no glue where to have a look at.

Using Micronaut 3.2.3 (but was also there with older versions) and Kotlin 1.6.10 on Gradle 7.1.1 within IntelliJ

Any help is welcome
Oli

added the ServerRepository

```
@Repository
@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
interface ServerRepository : PageableRepository<ServerData, Long> {
    fun findByName(name: String): List<ServerData>
    fun findByHost(host: String): ServerData?
}
```

And the ServerData

```
@Entity(name = "Server")
@Table(name = "server")
data class ServerData(
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    var id: Long = 0,
    @Column
    var name: String = "",
    @Column(unique = true)
    var host: String = "",
    @Column(unique = true)
    var port: Int = -1,
    @Column(unique = true)
    var password: String = ""
)
```

Comment: added the repo. There are no error logs, and the repo is not realy rocket science ;-)

Comment: Currently event recompile or restart the app does not fix the issue. In the past, sometime that helps. Also updating dependencies sometimes helps.

Comment: I run it locally in the IDE, i think thats a controlled environment. Currently i am debugging the Bean creation .. maybe i could find something there. My guess is that its something like a 'race condition' or depends on any order somewhere ..

Comment: What i found up to now, is that the beanConcreteCandidateCache within DefaultBeanContext contains an optional empty for 'repository'

Comment: Now i manage to work around, by fixing the annotations from `de.sambalmueslie.games.hll.*` to `de.sambalmueslie.games.hll.tool.*` but i am pretty shure the issue will come back

Comment: and here we go .. after adding a little more code, the issue is back again .. i know its hard to say help. I am myself work with micronaut for nearly 2 years. i had also the same idea with the initial delay. But switched to @Context, cause that should shurely work

Comment: I am also doubt that is something with micronaut alone. Having a service with a simple repository .. i did that 1000 times .. as singleton and also as context. maybe some weird combination of java, gradle, intellij and micronaut ..

Comment: A couple of weeks ago, I implemented the exact same thing: a call to a repository method from a scheduled job with Postgres as db. The app has been running in a GKE cluster without problems since the implementation. I guess we'll need @JeffScottBrown for this issue then.

Comment: I uploaded the project here: https://github.com/sambalmueslie/hll-tool

Comment: This issue from 2020 has both similar config and symptoms, and is not marked as resolved. https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-flyway/issues/77
Killed some of my previous messages before admin comes around :-)